# Unix command to find the files in one directory but not another?

Tags: unix

What is the unix command to find files that are in one directly buy not another directory? I only care about file names.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can say `ls dir1 dir3 dir5`.  If that’s not what you’re looking for, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this search from a higher level directory.  If so, you can use the `-path` option with `find`.

For example, given the directory structure below

```
+---dir1/test1.txt
  |
  |--dir2/test1.txt
```

to find files matching 'test*' in dir1 use

```
find -path '*dir1*' -iname 'test*'
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two directories, you can use this:

```
diff <(cd "$dir1"; find | sort) <(cd "$dir2"; find | sort)
```

To do this only one way, and produce a list of files, try this:

```
diff <(cd "$dir1"; find | sort) <(cd "$dir2"; find | sort) \
| grep '< ./' | sed "s,< ./,$dir1/,"
```

For this to work properly, neither $dir1 nor $dir2 should include the trailing slash.